# Automatically wrapping values for the duration of a statement

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to automatically wrap a value in a temporary whose lifetime extends across the entire statement?

---

Originally I hoped a solution or alternative to my problem would present itself [while writing the details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) for the question, unfortunately that didn't happen, so...

I have an abstract base class `Logger` that provides a streaming-like interface for generating log statements. Given an instance `logger` of this class, I want the following to be possible:

```
logger << "Option " << variable << " is " << 42;
```

Unlike regular streams, which simply generate a string from all the components (4 components in the example above), I want to generate an instance of a class `Statement` that manages a linked list of all the statement's components. The entire statement is then passed via pure virtual method to a class derived from `Logger`, which can iterate over all the components of the statement and do whatever with them, including obtaining information about their type, retrieving their value, or converting them to a string.

The tricky bit: I want to do the above without dynamic memory allocations. This means that every component of the statement must be wrapped by a temporary type that links the components into a traversable list, within the scope of the statement!

[I posted a working example on ideone](https://ideone.com/dom6vU), with one problem: every component needs to be wrapped by a function call in order to generate an instance of the temporary type. The log statement therefore ends up looking like this:

```
logger << wrap("Option ") << wrap(variable) << wrap(" is ") << wrap(42);
```

All my attempts to get rid of the `wrap` function (e.g., using an implicit converting constructor for the component), have failed thus far, therefore this question.

---

How can the components of the log statement automatically be wrapped in their component type (e.g., using a converting constructor for the component), without the need for an explicit call to a wrapping function?

Alternatively, I would appreciate suggestions for other ways that achieve the same effect, i.e., allowing iteration over the components of the log statement in a class derived from logger, without dynamic memory allocations.

---

Reference: Full code on ideone:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct Statement;
struct Logger;
struct ComponentBase;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct ComponentBase {
    mutable ComponentBase *next;
    ComponentBase() : next(nullptr) { }
    virtual std::string toString() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct Component : ComponentBase {
    T value;
    Component(T value) : value(value) { }
    ~Component() { }
    virtual std::string toString() {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << value;
        return ss.str();
    }
};

struct ComponentIterator {
    ComponentBase *ptr;
    ComponentIterator(ComponentBase *ptr) : ptr(ptr) { }
    ComponentBase &operator*() { return *ptr; }
    void operator++() { ptr = ptr->next; }
    bool operator!=(ComponentIterator &other) { return (ptr != other.ptr); }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct Statement {
    Logger *logger;
    ComponentBase *front;
    ComponentBase *back;
    ComponentIterator begin() { return front; }
    ComponentIterator end() { return nullptr; }

    template <typename T>
    Statement(Logger &logger, Component<T> &component)
    : logger(&logger), front(&component), back(&component) { }
    ~Statement();

    template <typename T>
    Statement &operator<<(Component<T> &&component) {
        back->next = &component;
        back = &component;
        return *this;
    }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct Logger {
    template <typename T>
    Statement operator<<(Component<T> &&component) {
        return {*this, component};
    }

    virtual void log(Statement &statement) = 0;
};

Statement::~Statement() {
    logger->log(*this);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename T>
Component<T const &> wrap(T const &value) {
    return value;
}
template <size_t N>
Component<char const *> wrap(char const (&value)[N]) {
    return value;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct MyLogger : public Logger {
    virtual void log(Statement &statement) override {
        for(auto &&component : statement) {
            std::cout << component.toString();
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::string variable = "string";
    MyLogger logger;
    logger << wrap("Option ") << wrap(variable) << wrap(" is ") << wrap(42);
}
```

Comment: I think it's possible to implement the syntax you propose, but why not simplify it by using a syntax like `logger("Option ", variable, " is ", 42);`? You could avoid the complexity of expression templates when using this approach..

Comment: Here `Statement &operator<<(Component<T> &&component) {
        back->next = &component;...
    }` you are moving an object and getting its address. Is this actually legal?

Comment: @dyp Yes, that would probably be the alternative I will go for if I can't find a way to remove the wrapping function call. However, if possible, I would prefer the more familiar streaming operator syntax.

Comment: @teivaz Good point. That's a relic of the process of writing the example code. The statement constructor can and should take a reference, not r-value reference, which makes the `std::move` unnecessary. Code is updated.

Comment: This is an abomination, but here you go: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07d563ee80919085

Comment: The level of abstraction/template madness going on here makes me shudder for the next maintainer of your code. Why isn't `Boost.Format` an option for you? (If you REALLY want to avoid dynamic allocation, use GNU's `autosprintf` but they (ab)use alloca to force all dynamic allocation to happen on the stack. That's not a good thing by the way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some crazy but working solution.

Having component implemented like this you will get rid of templates all over your code:

```
struct Component 
{
    mutable Component *next;
    typedef std::function<std::string()> ToStringFunction;
    ToStringFunction toString; // <-- 1

    template<typename T>
    Component(const T& value) 
        : next(nullptr),
        toString(nullptr)
    {
        toString = [&value](){
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << value;
            return ss.str();
        };
    }
};
```

Where (1) is the unction that knows what to do. This member `std::function` is a space for optimization.

And the rest of the code should look like:

```
struct ComponentIterator {
    Component *ptr;
    ComponentIterator(Component *ptr) : ptr(ptr) { }
    Component &operator*() { return *ptr; }
    void operator++() { ptr = ptr->next; }
    bool operator!=(ComponentIterator &other) { return (ptr != other.ptr); }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct Statement {
    Logger *logger;
    Component *front;
    Component *back;
    ComponentIterator begin() { return front; }
    ComponentIterator end() { return nullptr; }

    Statement(Logger &logger, Component &component)
        : logger(&logger), front(&component), back(&component) { }
    ~Statement();

    Statement &operator<<(Component &&component) {
        back->next = &component;
        back = &component;
        return *this;
    }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct Logger {
    Statement operator<<(Component &&component) {
        return{ *this, component };
    }

    virtual void log(Statement &statement) = 0;
};

Statement::~Statement() {
    logger->log(*this);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct MyLogger : public Logger {
    virtual void log(Statement &statement) override {
        for (auto &&component : statement) {
            std::cout << component.toString();
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::string variable = "string";
    MyLogger logger;
    //logger << wrap("Option ") << wrap(variable) << wrap(" is ") << wrap(42);
    logger << 42;
    logger << variable << " is " << 42;
    logger << "Option " << variable << " is " << 42;
}
```

this will print:

> 42 
>   string is 42  
>   Option string is 42

---

UPD
as dyp advised here is alternative implementation of the `Component` structure without lambda:

```
struct Component
{
    mutable Component *next;
    void* value;
    std::string toString(){
        return _toString(this);
    }

    template<typename T>
    Component(const T& inValue)
        : next(nullptr),
        value((void*)&inValue),
        _toString(toStringHelper<T>)
    {}
private:
    typedef std::string(*ToStringFunction)(Component*);
    ToStringFunction _toString;

    template<typename T>
    static std::string toStringHelper(Component* component)
    {
        const T& value = *(T*)component->value;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << value;
        return ss.str();
    }
};
```

Comment: @dyp this was in earlier versions of my solution but the function pointer should accept as an argument instance of the `Component`

Comment: @dyp I don't know what were the requirements for the syntax. if it is ok to have `component.toString(component);` than surely we can get rid of lambda.

Comment: @dyp Haven't thought about that! Good idea.

Comment: `_toString(toStringHelper<T>)` will not perform ADL for `toStringHelper` and therefore won't find the `friend` function. A simple solution is to make `toStringHelper` a `static` function instead of a `friend` function.

Comment: @dyp how did you detect it? It compiled and ran well in MSVC and GCC 4.9.2

Comment: It doesn't compile with neither g++ nor clang++ on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/036d135daf87c214

Comment: @dyp I've fixed it, thanks. But why does this happen? Need to check standard on that

Comment: A function declared only as a friend function within the body of a class can only be found via ADL. It is not visible in the enclosing namespace unless you add a declaration of that function there. ADL is only applied for function-call-expressions, and `toStringHelper<T>` is not a function-call-expression (it's not a postfix-expression but just an id-expression).

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution tuple based:

```
template <class... Ts> class streamTuple;

struct Logger {
    template <typename T>
    streamTuple<T> operator<<(const T& t);

    template <typename Tuple, std::size_t ... Is>
    void dispatch(const Tuple& tup, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        int dummy[] = {0, (void(std::cout << std::get<Is>(tup) << " "), 0)...};
        static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid unused variable warning
    }

    // Logger can take generic functor to have specific dispatch
    // Or you may reuse your virtual method taking ComponentBase.
};

template <class... Ts> class streamTuple
{
public:
    streamTuple(Logger* logger, const std::tuple<Ts...>& tup) :
          logger(logger), tup(tup) {}

    streamTuple(streamTuple&& rhs) : logger(rhs.logger), tup(std::move(rhs.tup))
    {
        rhs.logger = nullptr;
    }

    ~streamTuple()
    {
        if (logger) {
            logger->dispatch(tup, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>());
        }
    }

    template <typename T>
    streamTuple<Ts..., const T&> operator << (const T& t) &&
    {
        auto* moveddLogger = logger;
        logger = nullptr;
        return {moveddLogger, std::tuple_cat(tup, std::tie(t))};   
    }

private:
    Logger* logger;
    std::tuple<Ts...> tup;
};

template <typename T>
streamTuple<T> Logger::operator<<(const T& t) {
    return {this, t};
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22159ea5f1da938e)

And usage:

```
int main() {
    Logger log;
    std::string variable = "string";
    log << variable << 42 << "hello\n";
}
```